# Set row names for several data frames

Tags: r

I have several data frames and I want to set the row names of each one to the values of their first column and then remove that column from the data frame. I'm stuck trying to do this in a programmatic way.

Each data frame looks like this:

```
df[1:4,1:4]
       V1 V2 V3 V4
1 DDX11L1  0  0  0

2  WASH7P  0  0  0

3 FAM138A  0  0  0

4 FAM138F  0  0  0
```

where V1 consists of gene symbols.

I want the rownames to consist of the values in V1, which is easy enough to do on a one-by-one basis with:

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[,-1]
```

I've been struggling to apply this logic to a loop or an apply function, but there's clearly something I'm just not getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have data frames `df1`, `df2`, ..., `dfn`, you can put them in a list `l` with something like:

```
l <- list(df1, df2, df3, dfn)
# or (if they're actually named with numbers at the end)
l <- mget(paste0("df", 1:n))
```

... and then you can process them all at the same time with:

```
l <- lapply(l, function(x) {
  rownames(x) <- x[,1]
  x[,-1]
})
```

If you just have a few data frames, it may save typing to just define a processing function and then apply it by hand:

```
proc.df <- function(x) {
  rownames(x) <- x[,1]
  x[,-1]
}
df1 <- proc.df(df1)
df2 <- proc.df(df2)
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many "right" answers to this, but most of them are similar to this:
[Apply a function to each data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791760/apply-a-function-to-each-data-frame)

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c('DDX11L1', 'WASH7P', 'FAM138A', 'FAM138F'), V2 = rep(0, 4), V3 = rep(0, 4), V4 = rep(0, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), V2 = rep(0, 4), V3 = rep(0, 4), V4 = rep(0, 4))
dfList = list(df1, df2)
newList <- lapply(dfList, function(df) {
    rownames(df) <- df[,1]
    df <- df[,-1]
})
```