# Subset of data where no factor level combination is NA for a given year

Tags: r, apply, reshape

I want data not only without missing observations for a given year, but also, for the other treatments' data to not be used from that year. I have other factors (and they're not all consistent across sites) but here's an example just with the site and trt combo. This is typical in that the number of rows varies too.

```
ok1<-data.frame(year=(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)),
                yield=c(NA,65,NA,45,34,65,43,88,NA,33,23,11,23,54,12),
                trt=c("ct","nt","dt"), site="a")
ok2<-data.frame(year=(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)),
                yield=c(21,22,23,NA,34,65,43,86,39,36,43,41),
                trt=c("ct","nt","dt"), site = "b")
ok<-rbind(ok1,ok2)
```

Of course, I can ask for a logical vector like

```
complete.cases(ok[,"yield"])
```

but that leaves me with yield data years like 1 in site a when it is missing for one trt. How can I use something like apply or by to get complete cases for each year?
First thing I thought was to cast, then do complete.cases on that somehow:

```
okc<-cast(ok, year~trt~site, value="yield")
```

The data for site b looks like

```
> okc
...
, , site = b

     trt
years ct dt nt
    1 21 23 22
    2 NA 65 34
    3 43 39 86
    4 36 41 43
```

So I want to get rid of year 2 completely only for site b. So next:

```
okl<-apply(okc,3,complete.cases) #data is complete on 3rd dimension, i.e for a given year at a given site
```

How do I use this to get rid of trt*site*year factor combos for each FALSE?
Now ordinarily with a data frame then you can use logical vector to get rid of what you don't want. But I'm not experienced and can't find an answer on how to apply this back to the array a la the df version above, like `(complete.cases(ok[,"yield"])`. How do I do complete cases either by factor combination (`by(ok[, 2:3], ok[,"years"], complete.cases` doesn't work) or on an array? Or is there something simpler? Can I substitute complete cases for the density function in [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791760/apply-a-function-to-each-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through each group defined by the combination of `year` and `site`, and only keep the groups that don't have any `NA` values:

```
ok[with(ok, ave(is.na(yield), list(year,site), FUN=sum)==0 ),]

#   year yield trt site
#4     2    45  ct    a
#5     2    34  nt    a
#6     2    65  dt    a
#10    4    33  ct    a
#11    4    23  nt    a
#12    4    11  dt    a
#13    5    23  ct    a
#14    5    54  nt    a
#15    5    12  dt    a
#16    1    21  ct    b
#17    1    22  nt    b
#18    1    23  dt    b
#22    3    43  ct    b
#23    3    86  nt    b
#24    3    39  dt    b
#25    4    36  ct    b
#26    4    43  nt    b
#27    4    41  dt    b
```

If your data is large, consider `data.table` for a speed boost:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(ok)
ok[, if(!any(is.na(yield))) .SD, by=.(year,site)]
```

Comment: This does what I need, but the time it takes to run goes up exponentially as the number of factors in "list" goes up. Elapsed time goes from 0.02 for 2 factors to 1.44 with 3 to 130.71 with 4. Any way to make this more efficient if I ever have more factors? Thanks

Comment: @Anomie - if you are dealing with a large number of groups/factors, then try data.table. See my edit in one moment.

Comment: Huge difference, basically instant.